# Ngnix is converting custom http code to 502 bad gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reverse-proxy

**Application Stack:**

- **Framework**: Rails, 5.1
- **Reverse Proxy**: Nginx, 1.10.3
- **App Server**: Passenger, 5.1.5

I am having my API only Rails 5 application which is run behind Ngnix reverse proxy. A few of my requests are having ***custom http codes viz. 2000, 2003 etc***.

But the problem is that Ngnix is converting custom responses from server to 502 and sending Bad Gateway thus. I haven't found anything helpful yet all over. Any pointers shall be appreciated. Thanks.

Nginx server block:

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name sport-staging.sports.com; 
  passenger_enabled on; 
  passenger_app_env staging; 
  root /var/www/sport/current/public; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all -- are you sure, that with code change to default, your app works perfectly without any issues? Just double check that issue is for sure in custom codes.

My opinion is that you should NEVER define any kind of your custom HTTP codes. If you have such need, then in 99.99% you are doing something wrong. Think, that this app will be handled by other developers in the future. How can they understand what means 2003 code?

My recommendation is rather then looking for an nginx hacks or change it settings, you should better standardize your app. Existing HTTP codes is already fully enough for handle any kind of things.

Also, as a solution, you can use kind of application specific codes in response JSON for such purpose.

Comment: I've already had the discussion with another team regarding the Custom codes, but they are adamant. So can't help in that. And obviously I am scratching Nginx documentation to help out over it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sachin I am very upset to hear this. Show them your thread :D

Comment: The last thing I can do is make layer in my application to map other team's custom codes to standard http codes and then follow that for every request involving those codes.